# Esconder e Mostrar DIV baseado em resposta do SELECT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o código a seguir e gostaria de que ao selecionar qualquer valor dentro do select "#cities" mostre a div ".dadosLoja" e que ela fique escondida a princípio, já aproveitando a pergunta tem outra coisa que não estou conseguindo que é colocar o valor "Selecionar" no select "#cities", seja como value ou com placeholder, nenhum funcionou (ps:as informações do select vem de outro JS).

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <span class="TituloLoja">Selecione sua localidade: </span>
            <select id="cities" class="empty" name="cities"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="row content" >
         <div class="well text-left">
            <div class="dadosLoja ">
                <span class="TituloLoja">Informações da Loja:</span><br />
                <label>Telefone: <span id="telefone"></span></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explicação:**

Para deixar a div `.dadosLoja` escondida, coloquei ela como `display:none;`. Quando uma opção for selecionada e esta for diferente de "Selecionar" o javascript muda display da div `.dadosLoja` para `display:block;`.
A opção "Selecionar" foi inclusa direto no html com a propriedade `selected`, sendo assim por padrão ela já vem selecionada.

**Resultado:**

```js
function selected(value){
var dadosLoja = document.getElementsByClassName('dadosLoja');
 if(value != "Selecionar"){
    dadosLoja[0].style.display = 'block';
  }else{
  dadosLoja[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <span class="TituloLoja">Selecione sua localidade: </span>
            <select onclick="selected(this.value)" id="cities" class="empty" name="cities">
              <option selected>Selecionar</option>
              <option>Teste 2</option>
              <option>Teste 3</option>
              <option>Teste 4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="row content" >
         <div class="well text-left">
            <div class="dadosLoja" style="display:none;">
                <span class="TituloLoja">Informações da Loja:</span><br />
                <label>Telefone: <span id="telefone"></span></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Você pode ver o código [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/341nL4rL/1/) também.

Comment: você pode por favor postar o conteudo do seu JSFiddle na resposta e deixar o link apenas de referência? Caso o link fique offline a comunidade SOpt pode continuar a consultar a essa pergunta.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela ajuda.